# How can I fade a vertical gradient horizontally at its tips?

Tags: html, css, transparency, gradient, linear-gradients

I'm struggling to find a nice way to fade a vertical gradient at its left and right sides. Basically a top-bottom gradient with the left-right ends faded to 0% opacity.

I need it to be a Transparent fade out so that it can be on top of images/videos.

Here is a quick visual of what I am aiming for:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: What you have there is not a linear gradient, it's a very *radial* gradient.

Comment: Is there any reason to avoid a png image file?

Answer (score 3):

Pretty Simple, You just need to add transparent in a linear gradient.

```css
div {
      background:linear-gradient(to right, transparent, #00F5CB, transparent);
      width: 100%;
      height:64px;
    }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Now make the solid color in the middle(#00F5CB) into a vertical gradient. That is what I want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Use [multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds). The first one is on top.

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, white 0%, transparent 30%, transparent 70%, white 100%),
  linear-gradient( to bottom, Lightgreen, Aquamarine);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Because the white-transparent-white gradient uses white to fade out, I cannot use this method for overlays ontop of images and videos. That is the particular issue here. How can I fade a vertical gradient out on its sides so that it can be over images?

Answer (score 0):

You can try multiple background like this:

```css
.box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 80px;
  margin:auto;
  background:
   radial-gradient(ellipse at top, #7ff5b0 20%, transparent 70%) top center/80% 100%,
   linear-gradient( to right, transparent 0%, #19d9ef 30%, #19d9ef 70%, transparent 100%);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
      color: ;
    color: ;
}
body {
  background:pink
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```